# Custom FT232 (FTDI) PCB not recognized

Tags: arduino, usb, ftdi

I am currently working on a prototype for an ESP32 retrofit for a home alarm system.  I am an aspiring electrical engineer and will be attending Miami University next year.

I am having trouble getting my computer to recognize my USB connection to the ESP, despite having the correct drivers installed on my Mac.  Even in the device inspector, my computer doesn't show the FT232 as connected.  I have rebuilt the schematic twice on my breadboard with no luck.  I have attached my schematic below which is based off the Sparkfun ESP32 Thing.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: 3.3V is coming from a regulator circuit which is powering the ESP from 12V.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Where's your 3.3V coming from?

Comment: And also, please post a screenshot of the PCB layout as well.

Comment: No PCB layout yet, I'm just prototyping on a breadboard for now.

Comment: How have you attached the FT232RL to a breadboard? USB signals don't like breadboards.

Comment: I have a micro USB breakout connected directly to the FT232 via male to female dupont wires.

Comment: Are you sure it's a real FT232? There have been issues of incompatibilities between FT232 drivers and fake/clone devices.

Comment: Twisting the dupont wires together as tightly as you can will only help the situation.

Comment: No crystal? Does FT232 not require external oscillator and pullup on Reset pin? (mobile now, I don't have access to datasheet)

Comment: I sourced the FTDI chip from Digikey, so I'm confident it's a genuine IC.

Comment: The FT232 has an internal oscillator.

Comment: @MarkU schematic looks fine. Compared it with a design I've previously used and it matches (except mine didn't have R3/R4).

Comment: Maybe it's a driver issue.  I am going to try installing the drivers onto a PC with no existing FTDI drivers....

Comment: Same result on another computer.  The only thought I have now is that I fried it.  I did have to use a 500°C soldering iron with wick to remove some bridges after hot air soldering at 300°C.....

Comment: Did you try to disconnect your LEDs, would it work?

Answer (score 1):

100 nF capacitor is missing on pin 17. It is needed for stability of internal 3V3OUT regulator.

Also, in all suggested application diagrams the VCCIO is tied to either VCC, or to 3V3OUT, which is an internal derivative from VCC. The configuration shown in OP question doesn't follow any of suggested diagram. I suspect that if the VCC and VCCIO are completely independent, internal POWER-ON-RESET might not function, and the chip logic may not start properly. It is highly recommended to follow manufacturer's suggested configurations precisely.

Answer (score -2):

Pin D + of the USB connector must go with pin 16
and pin D- of the same USB connector connects to pin 15.

The lines are reversed in your project.

I hope this observation is useful.

Comment: That's completely wrong answer. The wires are not reversed. DP is 15 and DM is 16.

Comment: echoing the above, this answer is completely wrong.

Comment: "I hope this observation is useful." It isn't. It's simply wrong.